# Support Browser Compatibility Testing using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit4

-After Cross browser check using selenium web driver how can we identify that the operation perform on web application is going right way on each browser?

-And How to check that web application supported in all browser or not or that support which browser?

Answer (score 0):

1. Try it. If it didn't fail, it passed.
2. Are we talking about an existing, public web application? Read the documentation on browser support. If it's one you are creating then you have to test it in each browser you want to support and make sure that it functions correctly.

Comment: But How can we identify that it functions correctly?

Comment: You didn't post any code or give any idea of what you are trying to test so I don't know how to identify if it functions correctly. The test completing with no errors is a basic level of validating the test worked... past that, you'll have to provide more info.

Comment: 1)http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-size-adjust.asp
In this link Browser Support for font-size-adjust Property is given. Only firefox browser is supported.  2) http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_js_font-size-adjust  This link contain example which is work only in firefox browser. --> if you open in any other browser then it don't work. And they also provide "Note" Like this-Note: The font-size-adjust property is only supported in Firefox.

Comment: Now my question is that in this same case how can we do automation using selenium webdriver with JUnit . In this case "Note" is provided so we can identify that only firefox is supported but what is the way when no "Notification" are provided